# XSLT: Get the closest item with a specified value defined? (Sitecore)

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I have the current structure;

```
Item 1
 - Subitem 1
 - Subitem 2
 - Subitem 3
 - - Sub subitem 1
 - - Sub subitem 2
 - - Sub subitem 3
 - - etc
```

I have a field that is only defined on "Item 1". Let's call it 'Header'.

When i am on "Item 1" its easy enough to extract this value, but what about when i am on the other items? Is there a way i can go through the tree (up) until i find a field called 'Header' and it has a value, and then stop and use this as a reference point in my sub items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look up the tree and find the closest element that contains a *Header* attribute with a value, something like this should work.

```
  <xsl:value-of select="(ancestor::*/@Header[.!=''])[last()]" />
```

This uses the `ancestor` axis to look up the tree and the xpath expression looks for any element with a *Header* attribute who's value is not empty.

A second filter is used to evaluate the *last* one. If there is more than one ancestor that has a `@Header` with a value, the *last* one would be the closest to the context node, because the result is in *document order*.

**EDIT:** An alternative way to find the same results, leveraging the fact that `ancestor` axis returns in *reverse document order* would be to put the filter criteria in the predicate for the `ancestor` axis step, select the first one(closest match to the context node), and then step into the @Header:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[@Header!=''][1]/@Header" />
```

Comment: Ahh - looks good. WOuld this code also work on "Item 1" in this example? (The item that contains the header value)?

Comment: Yes, it should work, but you can change it from matching on any element(i.e. *) to the specific element name Item1 to be a more specific match.

Comment: The ancestor axis is sorted in reverse. The "closest" `@header` is not `[last()]`, it's `[1]`.

Comment: @Tomalak - You are correct that ancestor axis is reverse order, but the xpath used evaluates the @Header is in another step and those results are in document order, requiring the predicate filter for last().

Answer (score 1):

If your current context isn't `Item 1` but rather one of its children, you can use the `ancestor` axis to get its data.

So, assuming your `Item 1` element has an attribute called `Header`, you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Item1/@Header"/>
```

This assumes your XML structure (which you really should have supplied in your question) looks like this:

```
<Item1 Header="a header">
  <Subitem1/>
  <Subitem2/>
  <!-- etc -->
</Item1>
```

And that the name "Item1" is unique in this structure.

Comment: +1. What's missing is the explanation that `<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Item1/@Header"/>` gets the closest @Header value by "accident". It selects all ancestor headers, and value-of looks at the first in the list only. Which happens to be the closest based on the sort order of the ancestor axis.