# XPath: get closest heading element (h1, h2, h3, etc.)

Tags: php, xpath

I want to select the heading element (whether h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 or h6) that is closest above the form using XPath in PHP.

```
<h2>Foo</h2>
<h3>Bar</h3>
<form>
    <input />
</form>
```

The example above should return the h3 (Bar) because it is closest to the form.

```
<h4>Kee</h4>
<form>
    <input />
</form>
```

This example on the other hand should return the h4 (Kee) because it is closest.

This query (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2216795/4391251) works fine for just the h2 tags. I could modify it for h1, h3, h4, h5, etc. but I want a catch-all query.

```
$headings = $xpath->query('((//form)[2]/ancestor::*/h2[.!=""])[last()]');
```

Basically I want something like this

```
$headings = $xpath->query('((//form)['.$i.']/ancestor::*/[h2 or h3][.!=""])[last()]');
```

Except for that doesn't return any results, and neither does (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/7995095/4391251)

```
$headings = $xpath->query('((//form)['.$i.']/ancestor::*/[self::h2 or self::h3][.!=""])[last()]');
```

What query will give the desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
$xpath->query('//form['.$i.']/preceding-sibling::*[self::h2 or self::h3][1]')
```

basically, the xpath get the first preceding sibling of `form[i]` that is of type `<h2>` or `<h3>` (or whatever, just list all other elements as needed in the xpath predicate).

Comment: Excellent! I ended up using it like this:
$headings = $xpath->query('((//form)['.$i.']/preceding-sibling::*[self::h2 or self::h3])[1]');

Comment: could you post sample HTML that reproduce the problem?

Comment: *AFAICS*, as explained in this answer, the xpath should return *only the first* preceding sibling of `form`, there is no chance it can return more than one element.

Comment: I had already erased the comment I had posted earlier, it was a mistake on my end. The query returns multiple headings (as expected) because there were multiple forms on the page (each with their own heading). The query works as supposed!

Answer (score 1):

Take the fist h before form

```
//form/preceding::*[starts-with(name(),'h')][1]
```

Comment: This one unfortunately also returned the Head element (as it also starts with h)

Comment: @Theo if there is no h elements between head and form :)

Answer (score -1):

```
/html/body/*[starts-with(name(),'h')]
```